# Filter Google sheet value using case inclusive var

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to keep content in a file that matches the file name.
It is working but I have problems with cases and I cannot do what I usually do : make everything in lowercases since the File name should not be changed.
For example filename is "iPhone X"
and in the cells I will have values like "iPhone X", "IPHONE X", "iphone X"
and even with a space after like "iPhone X "

Is there any way to do that ?

Here is my code

```
//Only keep data that contains the file name
  var name = spreadsheet.getName();
  let range = sheet.getDataRange(),
      maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows(),
      srchCol_1 = 2,
      srchPatt_1 = new RegExp(name)
      newRangeVals = range.getValues().filter(r => r[0] && srchPatt_1.exec(r[srchCol_1])),   
      numRows = newRangeVals.length;  
  range.clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(2,1, numRows, newRangeVals[0].length).setValues(newRangeVals);
  sheet.deleteRows(numRows + 1, maxRows - numRows);
```

Comment: You can try and find out about `string.trim()` and `/i` for regex.

Answer (score 0):

Description

Here is an example of how to match strings containing the same characters in order but with space or no space.

Script

```
function test() {
  try {
    var name = "iPhone X Y Z";
    var names = ["iPhoneXYZ","iphonexyz","iphonexy","IPHONEX Y Z","IPHONEY"];
    name = name.replace(/\s/g,"").toLowerCase();
    console.log("name = "+name);
    names.forEach( item => { if( item.replace(/\s/g,"").toLowerCase() === name ) console.log("matched "+item) } );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

9:11:27 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:11:28 AM  Info    name = iphonexyz
9:11:28 AM  Info    matched iPhoneXYZ
9:11:28 AM  Info    matched iphonexyz
9:11:28 AM  Info    matched IPHONEX Y Z
9:11:27 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Reference

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just add `"i"` in the 2nd parameter of `new RegExp()`.

Your code should go from:

```
srchPatt_1 = new RegExp(name)
```

To:

```
srchPatt_1 = new RegExp(name, "i")
```

The 2nd parameter of `new RegExp()` is for flags. `"i"` is for **case insensitive**: no difference between A and a.

**Example:**

[image]

After executing code:

[image]

### Reference:

- [Regex Patterns and flags](https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction)
- [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)